# How to logout user from previous device in sails.js in mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, sails.js

I am working on a sailsjs Rest api that is used in android and ios for a chat app. 
I need to disable multi device signup and logout the user from the old device if they login in another device like whatsapp.

Comment: First of all this is not an Android question, second, this is opinion based and third show `what you did first`

Answer (score 1):

There should be a session key. For every web service, there should be verification of that session key. Without session key webservice should not be valid. By this it will be easy to track. Once a user gets log in to device, that user should be session key and that session key should be store in user device(for using valid web service call). If the same user log in on other device that user should be given new or updated session key. And this is the point. Now the user with same user has updated session key. If web service is hit with previous user with old session key, server should not allow the old user. And can response via flag (like not authentic call == false). If this case comes. You need to log out user from the app. I hope this will help you.

Comment: We need to pass the session key in every API call ?

Comment: yes, by this you will be able to know if service call is valid. Let's suppose old user using app and hitting service and he is in middle of the app. If you don't pass session key in every call then user in the middle of the app will keep on using the app. But by keeping session key in every call if the user is in the middle of the app will no longer be able to use your app. :)

Comment: I dont understand how we do it is sailsjs because now including session in every api call will be difficult

Comment: I don't understand this. Is there a built-in way to sails do this session stuff? @Sanish may you please add your final codes? Abdul may you please add some codes/configs?